# How to configure the update interval for Yahoo! Pipes?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I am creating some RSS using Yahoo! Pipes, but the update interval is too long. How can i change it? If it is not possible to change, how long it is exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pipes docs says it [honors the standard HTTP expiration headers](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=troubleshooting#q5), so it depends on  your sources' headers.

However, there is also a minimum interval, [this post](http://www.daybarr.com/blog/2008/02/12/yahoo-pipes-caching-and-robotstxt) claims it's around 10 minutes.